# Gensim data parsing

Tags: python, gensim

Okay, this is a specific question about what data structure is required when providing training data to the Gensim python library. In particular, there must be an implicit understanding of what constitutes a document in any data that it is provided (otherwise it wouldn't, for instance, be able to find the tf-idf).

For a specific example, the wikipedia dump is used in the tutorials for the library for training purposes. The wikipedia dump is provided in XML. What gives gensim an understanding of separate documents? Is this understanding predicated on the nesing of xml elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in the first two Gensim tutorials, [Corpora and Vector Spaces Tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html) and [Corpora and Vector Spaces](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut2.html). They walk you through all the steps with code examples.

They start with a `documents` object (a list of strings), show how to create a dictionary and a corpus out of it, and how to use the dictionary and corpus to create models such as LDA and LSI.

As can be seen in the [Experiments on the English Wikipedia](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html) tutorial example code, the dictionary and the corpus are read from serialized files. I recommend to go through all the [tutorials](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html) and the example code.

Answer (score 1):

Gensim is data source agnostic. For most of its functionality, it just requires a list of sentences as a document. Actually these documents can even consist of made-up words (i.e. for using word2vec [on graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6652)).

For parsing wikipedia dumps and other common corpus types, it provides [some utility classes](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/tree/master/gensim/corpora). Check its [API docs](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/apiref.html) of `corpora.*`